# Random string or text in phpmailer

Tags: php, xampp, command-line-interface, phpmailer

I'm trying to generate random numbers in phpmailer via cli(xampp) to send emails with random numbers

```
function Random($monat = 10) {
    return substr(str_shuffle("1234567890"), 0, $monat);
}
$ngntd = Random($monat = 10);
```

i used this code and some code from internet, it works but he sends the same number when i send is there any solution, to have him send random number every message?

Comment: The solution is [in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle). I would suggest using [random_int()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php).

Comment: can you give an example of the code

Comment: Yes: `$ngntd = random_int(0, 10);`. You can vary the range, of course.

Answer (score 0):

make a random digits generator with custom length:

```
function randomdigit($len)
    {
        $characters = '123456789';
        $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
        $randomString = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++) {
            $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
        }
        $pin=$randomString;
        return $pin;
    }

$ngntd = randomdigit(6); // e.g: 654321
```

Comment: it worked, but the result is the same, when i sent 5 different e-mail messages in 1 time the number only it didn't change

Comment: because you generate the code one time! for each email, generate it separately. for example generate it in your sending loop.

Comment: isn't there a way, to have each message return a different number?

Comment: would you mind if you plz send a screenshot of your code?

Comment: i used your code, it works but it sends the same code at all send. this is an example of the result https://ibb.co/Vw2nd5J

Comment: i want him to send random message once send, is there any way?

Comment: sorry but the details are not enough! please send me your php code just where ever you are creating "TEST digits". (with some of previous and next lines)